# return what is exclusively in one of two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frames and would like to return all rows in 'egress' that are not 'both'.  `setdiff` does not seem to do the trick.  In this example, I would need a new data frame with 7 rows returned.  How can I do this?

Part of my problem may be that I compute 'both', which sometimes truncates the trailing 0. 
'egress' is another data frame.
'both' contains rows that are in both the 'ingress' and 'egress' data frames.

```
both = merge(ingress,egress,by=c("lat","lng")
```

**egress**

```
       lat       lng
1  13.8333   44.6833
2  31.1429  -81.4710
3  37.4020 -122.0780  (match)
4  33.9553  -83.3937
5  33.9553  -83.3937
6  38.9628  -95.2554
7  18.9667   72.8333
8  38.8147  -77.0647
9  32.5670  -84.9870  (match)
10 30.5670  -85.9870  (match)
```

**ingress**

```
      lat       lng
1 38.8787  -77.1019
2 52.2500   21.0000
3 37.4020 -122.0780
4 40.7811  -74.0648
5 32.5670  -84.9870
6 30.5670  -85.9870
```

**both**

```
     lat      lng
1 30.567  -85.987   (trailing 0 is truncated)
2 32.567  -84.987   (trailing 0 is truncated)
3 37.402 -122.078   (trailing 0 is truncated)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I'd likely do. (If you've got concerns that sometimes just one of the data.frames will include trailing zeros, you may want to first use something like `sprintf()` to make the formatting of the two data.frames identical.)

```
A <- apply(egress, 1, paste, collapse="_")
B <- apply(ingress, 1, paste, collapse="_")
egress[! A %in% B, ]
#       lat      lng
# 1 13.8333  44.6833
# 2 31.1429 -81.4710
# 4 33.9553 -83.3937
# 5 33.9553 -83.3937
# 6 38.9628 -95.2554
# 7 18.9667  72.8333
# 8 38.8147 -77.0647
```

Comment: Can you (or someone else) please explain what the apply() function is doing?

Comment: @jftuga --  `apply()` is essentially slicing your data frame one row at a time, and (because you tell it to `paste`) it's pasting together the elements in each row. The `1` is really `MARGIN = 1`, telling `apply()` to operate row-wise (`MARGIN = 2` would have it operate column-wise). Finally, everything after the third argument (here `sep="_"` is passed on as an argument to `paste()`. If the logic is clearer, you could instead use something like: `A <- with(egress, paste(lat, long, sep="_"))`

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a dummy variable on `ingress` for later subsetting.

```
ingress$both <- 1
not_both <- merge(egress, ingress, by=c("lat","lng"), all.x = T)
not_both <- subset(not_both, is.na(both))
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I think Josh's answer is going to work out slightly better for my particular needs. Thank you!